# Convert a PHP variable from a number to a name

Tags: php

I have a PHP Variable`<?php echo $var; ?>` where `var` will return a number, for example `123456789`

I would like to display the variable as a word for example where `123456789` it would alias too `Dashboard`

Used in this context.

`<h1 style="text-align: center;">Specific settings for <?php echo $var; ?></h1>`

Currently returns.
`Specific settings for 123456789`

Where I would like to to show.
`Specific settings for Dashboard`

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use associative arrays in `PHP` to declare alias:

```php
$aliases = array(123456789=>"Dashboard", 987654321=>"Home");
echo $aliases[123456789];
```

Your code should like:

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Specific settings for 
   <?php echo $aliases[$var]; ?>
</h1>
```

Don't forget to declare aliases before use

Comment: Thank you.. This worked perfectly. 

Are you able to advise how I can incorporate this into this snippet too?

`<h1 style="text-align: center;">Select your Dashboard</h2>
    <div class="buttons">
        <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION["guilds"]); $i++){
            echo '<a href="guild.php?guild_id='.$_SESSION["guilds"][$i].'"><button class="guild">'.$_SESSION["guilds"][$i].'</button></a>';
        }
        ?>`

Where`guild` is the number variable

Comment: Are you meant with `$_SESSION["guilds"][$i]` as a whole have a numeric value OR  just `guilds` itself a variable have numeric value?
if 1st scenario is right then `$aliases[$_SESSION["guilds"][$i]]` otherwise if 2nd scenario is right then `$aliases[$guilds]`

Comment: Yes `$aliases[$_SESSION["guilds"][$I]]`Was the perfect Answer. Thank you :-)